# How do I set count using Mailchimp API PHP client library

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have installed the Mailchimp PHP client library on my web app and want to generate a list of all the tags I have used. The stock code works but seems to be limited to 10 responses. If I use curl instead the library functions I can set the count parameter and get all 25 tags. It doesn't seem like the library function accepts the count as in input. How can I get more than 10 tags returned using the library?

My working, albeit limited, library code is:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/includes/mailchimp/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();
$client->setConfig([
    'apiKey' => $MC_apiKey,
    'server' => 'us17'
]);
$response = $client->lists->tagSearch($MC_listID);
var_dump($response);
```

I can get all 25 tags if I use curl url such as this:

```
$MC_url = 'https://' . $MC_dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $MC_listID . '/tag-search?count=50';
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but can't find any help in the library's documentation. If you already found a solution please add another answer. Hopefully the library developers will add the possibility to set/use these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Tags are actually Segments (but of static type) in Mailchimp, you can use the ListSegments method.

The function is declared as:

```php
public function listSegments($list_id, $fields = null, $exclude_fields = null, $count = '10', $offset = '0', $type = null, $since_created_at = null, $before_created_at = null, $include_cleaned = null, $include_transactional = null, $include_unsubscribed = null, $since_updated_at = null, $before_updated_at = null)
```

So, to get the number of all tags or static segments you can start with the call:

```php
$response = $client->lists->listSegments($MC_listID, "total_items", null, null, null, "static");
```

After reading the total_items value you can do pagination by yourself (if needed = if there's more than 1000 items). Since the count parameter is limited to 1000 max, you'd need to walk through the list by yourself with count of 1000 and offsets of 0, 1000, etc (depends of how many *pages* you need to read. Something like:

```php
$response = $client->lists->listSegments($MC_listID, "segments.id,segments.name,segments.type", null, 1000, 0, "static");
$response = $client->lists->listSegments($MC_listID, "segments.id,segments.name,segments.type", null, 1000, 1000, "static");
$response = $client->lists->listSegments($MC_listID, "segments.id,segments.name,segments.type", null, 1000, 2000, "static");
...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, however the last code block is incorrect. It should use the listSegments method instead of tagSearch. Would be great if it could be updated for future users.